# javascript 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, npm, bower

i am trying to use bower with django framework.i done with following things.
Installed bower with sudo.
Installed packages with vrsion:-
npm: 3.5.2-0ubunt, 
nodejs: 4.2.6~dfsg-1,
bower: 1.8.2

and here is my following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/foundation.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    alert("hello");
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <span class="primary label">Primary Label</span>
                <span class="secondary label">Secondary Label</span>
                <span class="success label">Success Label</span>
                <span class="alert label">Alert Label</span>
                <span class="warning label">Warning Label</span>
        </body>
        </html>
```

but received 404 error in my browser network tab.please tell me what is the correct method to get work bower in django.

Comment: Just saying, switch from bower to npm with webpack

Comment: i will try it definitely sir. But what is the reason behind not working a code?

Comment: I'm not seeing what this has to do with bower, except that you are apparently trying to load a script from `bower_components`.  Does this script not exist?  What bower commands did you use?  Are you getting some error message?  It's really not clear what your issue is here.

Comment: i am user bower as package manager. i use command:  bower install jquery --save  which install jquery inside bower_components folder. then i user directory inside script to work my alert function,but alert msg is not pop up, not showing result. same i did with zurb foundation package.

Comment: hello, anyone watching my post? is any one trying to figure out?

Answer (score 0):

my jquery package which has installed with bower working now.the 404 error has gone.here it is what i have done.
my django project directory till the template folder is:

```
DjangoProject/DjangoProject/App/templates/
```

and my static folder directory is:

```
DjangoProject/DjangoProject/App/static/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

i place my static folder in position where templates folder is present and put directory for my js code like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <script src="/static/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/static/bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    alert("hello");
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <span class="primary label">Primary Label</span>
                <span class="secondary label">Secondary Label</span>
                <span class="success label">Success Label</span>
                <span class="alert label">Alert Label</span>
                <span class="warning label">Warning Label</span>
        </body>
        </html

the code has working fine for me now with 200 status code.thanks every one.
```